# Provider Hosted App stuck on installation

Tags: sharepoint-online, installation, provider-hosted-app

I'm working on provider hosted app in `visual studio C#`. But the project stuck on while installation.

```
3>  Installation is in progress (00:13:09)
3>  Installation is in progress (00:13:11)
3>  Installation is in progress (00:13:13)
3>  Installation is in progress (00:13:15)
3>  Installation is in progress (00:13:19)
3>  Installation is in progress (00:13:21)
3>  Installation is in progress (00:13:23)
```

I tried to `retract app`. After that `clean app`. Change the version number from `AppManifest.xml`. Restart visual studio. Restart PC. ReCreate `Site Collection`.

I hope someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a global issue.

Please open a request for Microsoft.

I guess it will be fixed "by itself" (they are working on it), but I wasn't given any specific date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Already it was worked by itself.